# Using find and grep to fill an array

Tags: arrays, bash, grep, find

In bash I am trying to produce an array of path-names to files with zero size.
I am using

```
find . -size 0
```

which gives me the list of files and their paths. So the Output is:

```
./001/013/fileA
./001/014/fileB
./002/077/fileA
```

Now I want an array that I can loop through, like this:

```
(001/013 001/014 002/077)
```

I tried this:

```
folderlist=($(find . -size 0 | grep '\<[0-9][0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>' ))
for i in "${folderlist[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

But the output is empty.

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of `grep` expressions, you could use `dirname` to get the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `dirname` to reliably get the directory path.

```
folderlist=($(find . -size 0 -print0|xargs -0 -I% dirname %))
for i in "${folderlist[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: This will break if filenames have space/newlines. Consider using -`print0`

Answer (score 2):

To strip just file names from `find` output you can use:

```
folderlist=($(find . -size 0 -exec bash -c 'echo "${1%/*}"' - {} \;))
```

Or to loop through those entries:

```
while read -r f; do
   echo "Processing: $f"
done < <(find . -size 0 -exec bash -c 'echo "${1%/*}"' - {} \;)
```